# How to assign variable sample names to an object based on the number of sample replicates in R?

Tags: r, list, analysis

I am trying to automate the analysis of an output from a new piece of equipment. The equipment has 6 wells (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3), and for my purposes lets say each well is a sample. So if I have 2 samples (Sample1 and Sample2), there would be 3 replicates of each sample (and for the sake of simplicity in this case I would always load the load the samples as A1=Sample1, A2=Sample1, A3=Sample1, B1=Sample2, B2=Sample2, B3=Sample2). So I want to make the script so that the only things I would need to change are the sample number and the sample names, so at the start I'd have something like (where NA can be change to a proper name if I had more samples):

```
SampleNumber <- 2
NoReplicates <- 6/SampleNumber
Sample1 <- "HIV-1"
Sample2 <- "CD3"
Sample3 <- NA
Sample4 <- NA
Sample5 <- NA
Sample6 <- NA
```

Basically I want to figure out a way to then apply those sample names to each well (for further downstream purposes) but based on the rule I said before and based on the sample numbers/number of replicates.

At the minute I have done it like this:

```
A1 <- Sample1
A2 <- Sample1
A3 <- Sample1
B1 <- Sample2
B2 <- Sample2
B3 <- Sample2
```

But obviously this requires me manually changing it and I want it to be automatic but my lack of experience/know how means I can't think of a way to do it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `list` is the exact right tag for this question. I'd suggest reading my answer at [How to make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) - it's the best I know how to communicate on this topic.

Comment: @GregorThomas many thanks for pointing me to your previous answer on the topic which I have found really helpful. Unfortunately, I am still unable to figure out how to resolve this query even with that info.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you have with the detail provided, but I would imagine your script using a vector or list. Instead of `Sample1 <- "HIV-1", `Sample2 <- "CD3"` you'd perhaps use `Sample <- c("HIV-1", "CD3")` and then maybe `wells = setnames(rep(Sample, length.out = 6), c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"))`. Then you use `Sample` and `wells` as vectors, you can access `wells[3]` or `wells["B2"]`. I don't understand your problem well enough from the info provided to give more guidance than that.

Comment: Hi Gregor, Thanks for getting back again. I've changed tactic and instead decided to keep everything in lists (which is what you were suggesting in the first place) and now it works a lot easier. Thanks again for the help!